# Is there a character for `biu`?

Tags: characters

`biu` is a fun onomatopoeia for the sounds guns and other shooting devices make.

This image is all over the net as the supposed character for `biu`

[image]

Is this correct?

I can't find much info on a ⿰口⿱比由 character.

Comment: I don't have evidence, but I want to believe that this is an artificial character created from the 反切 process. 比bi3 由you2 sounds very much like biu1 (I use biu1 but the picture suggests biu4) and 口 suggests an onomatopoeia.

Comment: I suppose you've already looked at [this](https://link.zhihu.com/?target=http%3A//www.jnnews.tv/news/2011-10/03/cms216785article.shtml), [this](http://www.chinanews.com/life/2011/10-02/3367674.shtml), or [this](https://www.zhihu.com/question/39009971)?

Comment: It's a fake, like that "biang" character, but less impossible phonologically in Mandarin/pinyin.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: No.
I know that such onomatopoeia is quite funny and useful, unfortunately they are quite recent that Chinese is too slow to generate a proper character for it.
The picture you showed is just a fake character that doesn't even exist.
So how do we express it?
Simple: Pinyin.
Another example: Duang.

Answer (score -1):

There is no biu in Chinese characters